# how can resolve messagebox shows in my codes using c#

Tags: c#

my code is here and messagebox shows multi times in my application when `(textBox1.Text != usernames[i] && textBox2.Text != passwords[i])`. do you have any idea to resolve it;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.Load(@"D:\myfile\login.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode item in xd.SelectNodes("mylogin/login"))
        {
            user += (item.SelectSingleNode("user").InnerText) + ",";
        }
        user = user.TrimEnd(',');

        usernames = user.Split(',');
        //==============

        foreach (XmlNode item in xd.SelectNodes("mylogin/login"))
        {
            pass += (item.SelectSingleNode("pass").InnerText) + ",";
        }
        pass = pass.TrimEnd(',');
        passwords = pass.Split(',');

        //============
        if (textBox1.Text != "" || textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < passwords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == usernames[i] && textBox2.Text == passwords[i])
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    new Form2().Show();
                }

                else
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("wrong");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please fill user & password");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide xml file also ?

Answer (score 1):

messagebox shows multi tilmes because you show it in loop, for each your usernames.

may be you need:

```
if (textBox1.Text == usernames[i])
            {
                if(textBox2.Text == passwords[i]) 
                {
                   this.Hide();
                   new Form2().Show();
                }                
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("wrong");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `break;` in your iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I am using bool variable to summarize the for loop result. If on exit on for loop check variable is true then i am showing message box. Hope it will help you.

```
   bool check = false;
   foreach (XmlNode item in xd.SelectNodes("mylogin/login"))
    {
        user += (item.SelectSingleNode("user").InnerText) + ",";
    }
    user = user.TrimEnd(',');

    usernames = user.Split(',');
    //==============

    foreach (XmlNode item in xd.SelectNodes("mylogin/login"))
    {
        pass += (item.SelectSingleNode("pass").InnerText) + ",";
    }
    pass = pass.TrimEnd(',');
    passwords = pass.Split(',');

    //============
    if (textBox1.Text != "" || textBox2.Text != "")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < passwords.Length; i++)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == usernames[i] && textBox2.Text == passwords[i])
            {
                this.Hide();
                new Form2().Show();
            }

            else
            {
               check = true;
            }
        }
        if(check)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Wrong");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please fill user & password");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
if (textBox1.Text != "" || textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            bool flag=false;
            for (int i = 0; i < passwords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == usernames[i] && textBox2.Text == passwords[i])
                {


                    flag=true;

                }

              }
               if(flag==true)
                {
                  flag=false;
                  this.Hide();
                    new Form2().Show();                      
                }
            else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("wrong");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("please fill user & password");
        }
```

Comment: If you like than accept my answer

Comment: my code write or wrong?

Comment: yes its work and correct

Comment: click write mark on front of my answer

Comment: this code has one error and is when try tow or three time to login but you cant login but for four time when use and pass is correct you see form2 three time be show

Comment: debug the code using f9 key then say what the error

Comment: http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-09/08617363075971034277.jpg  see the picture.when is happen that first for three times wrong users and password is selected but when user and password is correct four form 2 is show

Comment: image not open and check your username & password using debug and addwatch functionality

Comment: Now try my updated code.

Comment: view my code - simple and without flags ;)